# High load average with NO CPU usage

Tags: linux-kernel, webserver, load

I have a webserver running on a VM and often we have high server load whose root cause has not yet found.

I have sofar tried to dig out some Disk activity, memory usage, swap usage and CPU usage during the incident

So far i have found the following.

High pgscand/s, pgsteal/s    %vmeff noticed during the load.
%vmeff is 100 %

03:00:01 PM      1.06     65.63    662.44      0.00   1790.95      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
03:10:01 PM      4.39     56.46   1744.16      0.00   2370.19      0.00    221.60    221.60    100.00

The server runs on Redhat 7.5. Webserver is Apache and there are no outside hits to the webserver to cause any load. There are also no cronjobs running.

I would like to know the root cause of the issue

Comment: Anyone has idea why load average increases when i see more pagefaults. Please advise

Comment: Have you checked `iostat`?